# IE8 can't render my website unless I add host to trusted sites

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have deployed my website to an external server and when I connect to it on IE, it doesn't render my page correctly unless I add the host to my trusted websites. It renders fine on chrome. Any idea what could cause this? I link the css/js on the top of the html like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/display.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are there any externally loaded files such as images?

Answer (score 2):

One thing I noticed about IE 7 and IE 8 is you will need to use `jquery-1.11.1.min.js` instead of `jquery-2.1.1.min.js`. `jquery-2.1.1.min.js` is only supported by IE 9+. That is most likely the problem.

Comment: the thing is it renders fine when run locally on IE. Only on the external server I get that issue.

Comment: Running it locally on IE using IE 8 standards and for sure not compatibility mode? Press F12 and make sure when on your localhost you are not in the wrong document mode (IE 8) and user agent string is also IE 8. Replace jquery-2.1.1.min.js with jquery-1.11.1.min.js on the server and try it again. IE 7 and IE 8 don't support jquery-2.1.1.min.js so it will not render as intended. Your localhost may be using IE 9+ or compatibility mode.

Comment: how do I check this after pressing f12?

Comment: ok, I'll try deploying with 1.11.1. Just takes a while to deploy so hope this works.

Comment: @SKLAK See what Document mode and User agent string is. If you don't see those it just means you have a lower IE version than me which is okay. Look for 2 drop down lists and you should see one with which IE to use and another the standard to use such as compatibility mode. Make sure they are both IE 8 and IE 8 Standards when running your localhost. But trust me, IE 8 does not support jquery-2.1.1.min.js replacing it with jquery-1.11.1.min.js should fix it up if it doesn't at least we will remove one thing that is  throwing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Many corporations have company-wide security policies set on Internet Explorer. These settings are usually the responsibility of your SysAdmins, or IT Ops guys (titles vary). The reason it differs from your IE at home is due to these extra security settings, and depending on the policy of your company it may be possible to add your external host to everyone's trusted sites list in one action by the SysAdmins. If not, then you will have to find alternatives. Locally hosted css and js should not matter in this case, the problem is more the unrecognized domain name.

The site works in Chrome because these settings are tied to Windows and Chrome does not integrate with those (a major reason why some companies for all non-developers to use IE for everything). Good luck, this problem falls under "battling the bureaucracy" as opposed to actual honest-to-goodness programming, but hopefully you'll prevail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is true that due to security reasons IE asks the user if it should access scripts from untrusted domain.  If it is jquery( jquery 2 not supported by IE8 use 1.11 or earlier ) that is being blocked by IE,  try using jquery from Google cdn. Google is trusted host I am sure.